# Back when I updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS [now 20.04.01] I noticed I have two "instances" of Firefox

Tags: 20.04, firefox, multiple-instances

I have two identical Firefox icons in my Activities list. Both icons appear in the Applications List located within Setting>Applications. As you can see in the attached image both are separate functioning installations. I assume one is the snap version [described in about as for canonical - 1.0] and one is the old apt version [described in about as for canonical-002 -1.0]. Opening the two I find that the one I typically use [canonical - 1.0] has all of my current extensions and bookmarks while the other is outdated. I know that in my home folder my .mozilla profile is associated with the version I use because it grows as I add extensions and bookmarks etc, or at least I assume so. I know that I can use apt remove firefox to remove the old one or snap remove to remove the new one. That said I am not sure.

I don't want to inadvertently uninstall the "version" that I have been actively tweaking. Before I proceed I will backup .mozilla.
Is it safe to assume the "apt" version is the old version with the about info of: "canonical-002 -1.0 Updates disabled by your system administrator?" If so, is sudo apt remove firefox the way to go?[About info's and lookup commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulWc3.png)

Comment: I may have just answered my own question. The 002 version is actually the "Snap" version as it shows right there in the about image I posted......  

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. If you are going to uninstall the snap version, you will need to [backup your firefox profile before you uninstall](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles#firefox:linux:fx83). Unlike uninstalling a deb package, uninstalling a snap removes your profile and configuration files! Also, if you have found an answer, you can post a solution to your own question to help others who may have the same problem. You will be able to mark your answer as the solution after a few days to give others a chance to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap version is a snap variant of firefox ,meaning that it will be updated automatically , the apt version  will need to  update using apt-get upgrade . You can remove either  from using terminal (apt-get remove firefox or use the ubuntu store for the snap version)

Comment: Thank you. "sudo snap remove firefox" did the trick. Ideally the snap version would have been the version I would have liked to keep, but I have made many customizations to the old apt version as that was the versions inherited from 18.04.